# Difference Between JQuery .html() method and Javascript .innerHTML = "<div> somediv </div>"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have done a fair bit of googling and looking at "you might not need jquery" but still haven't been able to figure out what is wrong.

I have a makeTable function that builds up a html string of elements to form a table.  The function works great when I append the output table to the DOM using the Jquery .html method.

Here is the function:

```
function drawTable () {
  var outputString = '';
  for(var i = 1; i <= 12; i++ ){
    outputString += "<tr>";
    for(var j = 1; j <= 12; j++) {
       outputString += "<td>" + i * j + "</>";
    }
    outputString += "</tr>";
  }
  $("#output").html(outputString);
}

drawTable();
```

However, when I don't use Jquery and I change `$("#output").html(outputString);` to `document.getElementById('output').innerHTML(outputString);` the table doesn't render on the page.     I just get a single line of numbers.  When I inspect the element, `<tr>` and `<td>` elements are not being rendered at all and I don't understand why.

I am confused.  How should I render this table in plain JS?  What am I not understanding about the innerHTML method ?  The functions are identical, I am just changing the line where outputString is appended to the DOM and really don't understand why it is not rendering correctly when I attempt to do it in plain JS.  Please enlighten me!

Comment: `"</>"` is not an end tag.

Comment: [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) is not a getter/setter method like jQuery's `.html()`, it's a property of a DOM element. You need to assign `outputString`, e.g. `element.innerHTML = outputString`.

Comment: @IgorRaush  Thanks, I changed the line to document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = outputString.  I do not get any console errors.  However - none of the '<tr></tr> or <td></td> elements render. When I inspect the element they are not there. All the page displays is a line of numbers.  How can I get the table to display using pure JS?

Comment: @user3562480 Make sure that your element with `id="output"` is a `<table>`. See [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/8iDBSzyxCdU2xTlpxfQ5?p=preview).

Comment: Thank you!  That fixed.  I would have never thought of that.  I wonder, why it is necessary to use that specific tag with the JS version but not the JQuery one... weird. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

@Igor Raush was correct in his comment. You are mis-using the innerHtml. It is not a method that takes a paramenter. It's a property whose value must be directly set with an equal sign.

In plain javascript:

```
document.getElementById("output").innerHtml = outputString;
```

In jQuery:

```
$("#output").html(outputString);
```

Comment: Hello, and thank you for your comments.  However, my Problem is the same as before:  None of the <tr></tr> or <td> </td> elements are rendered.

Comment: When I run this function :

Comment: function drawTable () {
          var outputString = '';
               for(var i = 1; i <= 12; i++ ){
                      outputString += "<tr>";
                     for(var j = 1; j <= 12; j++) {
                              outputString += "<td>" + i * j + "</td>";
                       }
             outputString += "</tr>";
          }

    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = outputString

  }

Comment: when I run the above code and change the the line in question to document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = outputString.  I do not get any errors, But the Table doesn't render.  All that appears is a long string of numbers.  When I inspect the element no '<tr></tr>' or '<td></td> ' elements are rendered.  What is the problem with pure JS version ? n

Comment: You're generating a table without table tags. So it's stripping out all the tr and td tags because there is no table tag to hold them. Check out this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fedyfztp/

Comment: Or if 'output' is a table then it works. Check this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fedyfztp/1/

Comment: Apparently the difference is that jQuery doesn't verify that the html being injected is valid html it doesn't care if there is a table tag it enters what you tell it. Where innerHTML is verifying that tr and td are only valid inside a table tag and therefore doesn't allow the invalid HTML.